# Unknown Linux Server Reset

Tags: linux, hp, hp-proliant, oracle, reset

We have a infamous box out of 4 running on the kernel version below.

**Linux **** 2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 11 11:09:04 PST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux**

The box now is suffering from restart without obvious logs unless from the iLO event logs

**Server Power restored**
**Server reset**

Anyone has similar case? and appreciated for your advice on how to determine the root cause?

Thanks,

Comment: Please specify the ***EXACT*** model of your HP ProLiant server. It's very important.

Comment: `infamous` I don't think that word means what you think it means. Better word to use would be "bad" or "faulty", unless your server is actually famous for its unethical behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a poor question because it doesn't provide some of the most basic information needed to help answer it.

But I was able to glean that this is an HP ProLiant server running Linux. The fact that you mention ILO, the type of error and the Linux kernel version, makes me believe this is an HP ProLiant DL380 G6.

This model had a [power controller issue](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01956744) that could result in the errors you're seeing.

It can be repaired via a firmware upgrade.

Comment: What specific model? DL380p Gen8?

Comment: It's in **ProLiant BL460c Gen8**. We have replaced the system board at least 15 days ago, but the issue still happens

Comment: You should deal with HP support then. Also be sure to upgrade your server's and bad chassis firmware.

Comment: thanks to @ewwhite anyway. we will swap out the infamous box tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Server Power restored can only mean that the power was off, so that does not indicate cause. Do you need to reboot or does it happen spontaneously? If you need to reboot, then look at the screen first, there may be kernel error. I would suspect a power error (are the machines double-PSU, are all the machines on the same power outlets, are the cables well plugged in?) or hardware error (are you monitoring temperature?). I'd replace the server and run it through testing, but I realize that may not always be an option. What does your hardware vendor support say?

Comment: Thanks to @Law29. The **Server Power restored** didn't mean that there was no power supply. As when we reboot the machine manually, we can see the iLO event too. We didn't see any abnormal logs from HP management portal.